# Simple XML parser in android not working

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, xml-parsing

app should parse XML and output to the and ListView, but it doesn't seem to work

my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView spiska;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spiska = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.spiska);
    try {
        MainActivity obj = new MainActivity ();
        String[] arra = obj.run ("http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/sportsNews?format=xml");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arra);

        spiska.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String[] run (String url) throws Exception
{

    String[] forlist = new String[100];
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory f =
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = b.parse(url);

        // loop through each item
        NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
            Node n = items.item(i);
            if (n.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                continue;
            Element e = (Element) n;

            // get the "title elem" in this item (only one)
            NodeList titleList =
                    e.getElementsByTagName("title");
            Element titleElem = (Element) titleList.item(0);

            // get the "text node" in the title (only one)
            Node titleNode = titleElem.getChildNodes().item(0);
            forlist[i] = titleNode.getNodeValue();
        }
    }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return forlist;

}
}
```

android studio outputs

Process: com.example.javarulit, PID: 15400
                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

and this code works for java

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hell o world");

    try
    {
        Main obj = new Main ();
        obj.run ("http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/sportsNews?format=xml");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }

}
public void run (String url) throws Exception
{
    String[] forlist = new String[100];
    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory f =
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = b.parse(url);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println ("Root element: " +
                doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        // loop through each item
        NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node n = items.item(i);
            if (n.getNodeType() != Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                continue;
            Element e = (Element) n;

            // get the "title elem" in this item (only one)
            NodeList titleList =
                    e.getElementsByTagName("title");
            Element titleElem = (Element) titleList.item(0);

            // get the "text node" in the title (only one)
            Node titleNode = titleElem.getChildNodes().item(0);
            forlist[i] = "\"" + titleNode.getNodeValue().toString() + "\"";
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(forlist));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `new MainActivity ()`... You can't do that... You really should add the logcat to the question, though

Comment: Why can't you just call `run(url)` directly from the Activity? Though, you are performing a network operation, so that won't work either. Look up how to use an AsyncTask.

Comment: just call run(url) directly from the Activity? you mean `String[] arra = run ("http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/sportsNews?format=xml");`

Comment: Yeah. It'll throw a different error, though

Comment: And when `items.getLength() >= forlist.length()`, you'll also get an exception. Should use a arraylist if you are going to name a variable a list

Comment: where use a arraylist?

Comment: In place of `String[] forlist`. If you aren't guaranteed exactly 100 elements, then don't use an array

Comment: ok. error disappeared. but Listview in app is empty

Comment: The problem is solved (partially). the code was not working because of the mainstream. I do not fully understand. but I will learn with time. thanks @cricket_007